# Sorting a Dataframe by column containing char-digit-char values

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a column in my Dataframe that has values that look like this (I want to sort my Dataframe  by this column):

```
Mutations=['A67D','C447E','C447F','C447G','C447H','C447I','C447K','C447L','C447M','C447N','C447P','C447Q','C447R','C447S','C447T','C447V','C447W','C447Y','C447_','C92A','C92D','C92E','C92F','C92G','C92H','C92I','C92K','C92L','C92M','C92N','C92P','C92Q','C92R','C92S','C92T','C92V','C92W','C92_','D103A','D103C','D103F','D103G','D103H','D103I','D103K','D103L','D103M','D103N','D103R','D103S','D103T','D103V','silent_C88G','silent_G556R']
```

Basically all the values are in the format of `Char_1-Digit-Char_2` I want to sort them with `Digit` being the highest priority and `Char_2` being the second highest priority. With that in mind, I want to sort my whole Dataframe by this column

I thought I could do that with `sorted()` with this list sorting function as my `sorted( , key=)`:

```
def alpha_numeric_sort_key(unsorted_list):
  
   return int( "".join( re.findall("\d*", unsorted_list)  )   )
```

This works for lists. I tried the same thing for my dataframe but
got this error:

```
df = raw_df.sort_values(by='Mutation',key=alpha_numeric_sort_key,ignore_index=True) #sorts values by one letter amino acid code

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I just need to understand whats the right way to understand how to use `key=` in `df.sort_values()` in a way thats understandable to someone that has an intermediate level of experience using Python.

I also provided the head of what my Dataframe looks like if this helpful to answering my question. If not, ignore it.

Thanks!

```
raw_df=pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 100}, 'Mutation': {0: 'F100D', 1: 'F100S', 2: 'F100M', 3: 'F100G'},
                 'rep1_AGGTTGGG-TCGATTAG': {0: 2.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 49.0, 3: 19.0},
                 'Input_AGGTTGGG-TCGATTAG': {0: 48.0, 1: 125.0, 2: 52.0, 3: 98.0}, 'rep2_GTGTGGTG-TGTTCTAG': {0: 8.0, 1: 40.0, 2: 33.0, 3: 11.0}, 'WT_plasmid_GTGTGGTG-TGTTCTAG': {0: 1.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0},
                 'Amplicon': {0: 'Amp1', 1: 'Amp1', 2: 'Amp1', 3: 'Amp1'},
                 'WT_plas_norm': {0: 1.9076506328630974e-06, 1: 7.63060253145239e-06, 2: 1.9076506328630974e-06, 3: 1.9076506328630974e-06},
                 'Input_norm': {0: 9.171121666392808e-05, 1: 0.0002388312933956, 2: 9.935381805258876e-05, 3: 0.0001872437340221},
                 'escape_rep1_norm': {0: 4.499235130027895e-05, 1: 0.000337442634752, 2: 0.0011023126068568, 3: 0.0004274273373526},
                 'escape_rep1_fitness': {0: -1.5465897459555915, 1: -1.087197258196361, 2: -0.1921857678502714, 3: -0.8788509789836517} } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the parameter `key` in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) it clearly says :

> It should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as
> the input. It will be applied to each column in by independently.

You cannot use a single scalar as a key to sort.

You can do sorting in two ways:

1. First way:

```py
sort_int_key = lambda col: col.str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False)
sort_char_key = lambda col: col.str.extract("(?<=)\d+(\w+)", expand=False)
raw_df.sort_values(by="Mutation", key=sort_int_key).sort_values(
    by="Mutation", key=sort_char_key
)
```

2. Assign extracted values as temporary columns and sort them using `by` parameter specifying those columns:

```py
raw_df.assign(
    sort_int=raw_df["Mutation"].str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False),
    sort_char=raw_df["Mutation"].str.extract("(?<=)\d+(\w+)", expand=False),
).sort_values(by=["sort_int", "sort_char"])
```

Comment: So if I have this right, then extract allows for a regex search and then extract allows you to capture the row index of where that regex search occurs so that the row as a whole can be manipulated and worked with?

Also, you can probably tell I wasn't too sure on how to present my dataframe on the forum. What's the appropriate format to use in my question since the data I'm working with is thousands of rows. Do I even need to put the dataframe in my question?

Comment: The regex extract allows us to create a series (in background) which serves as key by which to sort. And yes you do need to put dataframe in the question to know what you are exactly looking for.